# Possible to Kill Processes using WMI Python

Tags: python, windows, process, wmi, remote-access

I know it is possible to create a process on a remote windows machine using the `WMI` module but I wish to know if the same can be said for ending a process. I havent been able to find a thread or any documentation for this so please if you can help me It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Win32_Process` has a [`Terminate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393907) method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer in case anybody else runs into a similar issue; You actually dont even need `WMI` and can be run directly from command prompt:

if you are in the same network you can issue a command via command prompt with the following format:

`taskkill /s [Computer name or IP] /u [USER or DOMAIN\USER] /p Password /pid [The process to kill i.e. notepad.exe]`
This will take a few moments but will eventuall kill the process that is running.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below WMI python library to terminate process

```
def terminate_process_id(self,process_id):
    for process in self.connection.Win32_Process (ProcessId=process_id):
        print(process.ProcessId, process.Name)

    try:
        process.Terminate()
        print("Process terminated successfully: %d" % process.ProcessId)
    except:
        print("There is no process running with id: %d" % process_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about using the WMI module but you can use [PsKill](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896683) to exit processes on a remote machine